# Проблема с PSQL 11. не берутся/не добавляются данные в базу

Tags: python, psycopg2, psql

я новичок в базах данных, до этого работал лишь с SQLite3. Решил пересесть на PSQL11. Работаю на Python 3.6.5 с библиотекой psycopg2. Создал базу, создал таблицу STUDENT на основе примера на этом [сайте](https://dev-gang.ru/article/rabota-s-postgresql-v-python-xn8721sq0g/). добавляю данные в базу, делаю Комит, а потом, когда делаю Селект, получаю None. в чем может быть проблема? Код программы приведен ниже.

```
import psycopg2
from random import randint

con = psycopg2.connect(
    database="name", 
    user="login", 
    password="password", 
    host="127.0.0.1", 
    port="5432"
    )
cur = con.cursor()
print('ПОДКЛЮЧЕНО')


cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  STUDENT  
     (ADMISSION INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     NAME TEXT NOT NULL,
     AGE INT NOT NULL,
     COURSE CHAR(50),
     DEPARTMENT CHAR(50));''')

print("Table created successfully")


cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(
  "INSERT INTO STUDENT (ADMISSION,NAME,AGE,COURSE,DEPARTMENT) VALUES (%s, 'John', 18, 'Computer Science', 'ICT')" % randint(0, 100000)
)

con.commit()
print(cur.execute("SELECT admission, name, age, course, department from STUDENT"))

con.close()
```

Результат работы программы ниже

```
ПОДКЛЮЧЕНО
Table created successfully
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные добавляется, а не берутся, потому что неправильно берёте. Для получения результата нужно использовать cur.fetchone() или cur.fetchall() ...
Тут есть примеры: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html

Comment: Спасибо огромное, заработало!
просто в SQLite3 подобная конструкция была вполне валидна.

Comment: а можно как-то в одну строчку делать, вместо
cur.execute("SELECT admission, name, age, course, department from STUDENT")
print(cur.fetchall())

Comment: Нет в одну не выйдет, либо самому оборачивать в функцию.
Как вариант, можно посмотреть в сторону pg8000, там вроде есть метод query